# Word for specific behaviour irrationally ascribed to gay people?

Tags: terminology

Nowadays, there seem to be a lot of men/boys who behave in my opinion, more feminine. For example saying "Oh my gosh" with a bit high voice and making gestures that mostly young woman do. Teenagers mostly call this person "gay", because stereotypes say that this behavior is mostly seen among homosexual men/boys. Not everybody who behaves like that, has to be gay. But is there any other word for this?

Comment: Camp comes to mind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[effeminate](https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all#hl=en&q=effeminate+meaning) or effete: (of a man) having or showing characteristics regarded as typical of a woman; unmanly.

Answer (score 3):

No, I'm pretty sure there isn't, for this reason:

**The only thing these attributes share is that some people inappropriately (and sometimes offensively) associate them with gay people.**

You can find some groupings with names - your post references some male gay stereotypes that could surely be described as "effeminate," but that wouldn't cover lots of other dopey misbegotten ideas, like that most gay men lisp, which has nothing to do with being feminine.

It's like any other group of traits people wrongly assign this way - the main thing they have in common is that some buffoons have irrationally grouped them together as pejorative associations with a group of people.

Comment: Well, let me be buffoon then. 'Cause I associate people with groups by type.

Comment: This is more of a philosophical/emotional response than one regarding the English language. I think there's nothing wrong in saying the behavior described by the OP is effeminate. The OP also stipulates that it's a *stereotype*.

Comment: @medica, the question title asks for a word that covers the various stereotypes people associate with gay people.  If the question is rather about a word for men who behave in ways more typically associated with females, I'd agree with you, but that would mean the references to "gay" stereotypes is sort of a red herring here.

Comment: @Guest, no name calling was intended.  I wasn't directing that term your way; I thought your post implied that you recognized the folly in assuming most members of a group would have the characteristics of a stereotype assigned to them by others.

Comment: Also, words mean that for which they are used for, regardless of how correct are those who use them. For example, the word *sinister* acquired its meaning of *being evil or threatening* also by a prejudice, in this case towards left-handed people. Sinister's original meaning was *left, or on the left, or left-handed*.

Comment: -1 Is there ever a reason for there not to be a word (or words) for something?

Comment: @Frank Yea, well, go for it that I am foreigner and I don't know that word. I don't know how to find it. I assume that most of you, English lingual teachers or just Anglo-phone people et cetera, could tell me whether such word exists and if it does, what is that word. Is that so hard to help someone who knows less and can't find it on his/her own?

Comment: @Guest My **-1** was for _Jaydles_ not you. **You are right to ask**, he is wrong to suggest there is no such word and even more wrong to suggest it doesn't exist for the reason he gave. In my opinion, the top answer from _EdwinAshworth_, **effeminate**, is the correct word you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Consider "[epicene](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/epicene)."

> **epicene**: 3. effeminate; unmanly.

Comment: Also a good one, I'd like to give you "Answering Tick" too, but, I can afford only one.

Answer (score 1):

I find the term 'stereotypically gay' to be of use. 
It differs from terms like 'effeminate', 'flamboyant', 'campy', or even 'androgynous' in that it does not exclude any particular aspect that might be attributed to gay people while acknowledging that just calling certain behavior 'gay' would be silly or offensive.

Answer (score 0):

**Prejudice** is the root of all the attitudes against gays or typical gay behaviours. **Prejudicial behaviour**.

Comment: I appreciate what you're going for here, but "prejudicial behaviour" is certainly not a term for "speaking in a high-pitched tone".